# get all the data until current month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with two columns MONTH and TEXT.

How can i display all the entries but not those that are in months that exceed current month?
(e.g. if i have text in March, August and December and we are in August, i only want March and August texts to be displayed.)

```
<?php

// select all data at once

$construct ="SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) = ???";
rest of code

?>
```

I want to have this because i will enter future month text and i don't want it displayed.

Comment: how do you store month data?

Comment: the date is in yyyy-mm-dd format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$construct ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) <= ".date('m');
```

Or in mysql you can try like

```
$construct ="SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) <= MONTH(CURDATE())";
```

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: used your idea and i made $construct ="SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) <= MONTH(CURDATE())";

Comment: Note that this doesn't take the **year** into account, so albeit it will show records from correct months, it will also show records from other years (and correct months).

Comment: that was only part of the code... the full code is $construct ="SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(DataIntroducere) <= MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(DataIntroducere) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY MONTH(DataIntroducere) DESC"; i am only interested in current year's texts

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible way to do it is to save the dates as unix timestamps.
http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Most programming languages provide methods that return unix timestamp. You can then convert current month into a timestamp and do query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month < timestamp_of_current_month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$construct = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(DataIntroducere) <= DATE(NOW());
```

This is the (correct) one. And you don't have to care about YEAR(), MONTH(), CURDATE() or whatever.

Comment: Oh. Ooh! Now I finally grasped the whole question. It's correct now, I hope :)

Comment: yup... it is ok... but still... i only want only for current year... :)